# Global Pose of Robot in Dynamic window approach

Tags: ros, nav-msgs, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pose from <nav_msgs::Odometry> is same as the pose from tf::Stamped<tf::Pose> ?
Are these similar. Can I use the pose from the /odom topic in a function which takes a parameter of type " tf::Stamped<tf::Pose> " ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61394/global-pose-of-robot-in-dynamic-window-approach/) by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you have to use a [transform listener](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29) to get the pose as a `tf::Stamped<tf::pose>` message type. If your function parameter needs `nav_msgs::Odometry` you use a standard ROS subscriber to get the pose as a `<nav_msgs::odometry>` message type.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-04-26**:
Thank you. Yes, it worked.